# No data on http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc

Tags: sapui5

I am trying consume an OData service(http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc) in SAPUI5 but it does not return any data

My controller code  is as below [image]

## Dialog.fragment.xml

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <SelectDialog
        title="Products"
        class="sapUiPopupWithPadding"
        items="{/CategoryName}"
        search="_handleValueHelpSearch"
        confirm="_handleValueHelpClose"
        cancel="_handleValueHelpClose">
        <StandardListItem
            
            title="{CategoryName}"
             />
    </SelectDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Comment: What shows on your chrome console? Any errors?

Comment: ----https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs.js?eval Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -----



---Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)----




---Uncaught (in promise) Object
sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/core/library-preload.js:1956 Uncaught (in promise) Object----



----Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)----

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an incorrect URI in your model declaration. The image shows the model path assigned as

```
var sServiceUrl = "8080/http/services.odata.org/V2/Odata/Odata.svc";
```

This is the reason for the 404 error, you will have to change this to

```
var sServiceUrl = "http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc";
```

Also, you have an invalid binding for your SelectDialog. The Odata [metadata](http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata) does no have a EntitySet named "CategoryName". You will have to change this to "Categories".

```
<SelectDialog
    title="Products"
    class="sapUiPopupWithPadding"
    items="{/Categories}"
    search="_handleValueHelpSearch"
    confirm="_handleValueHelpClose"
    cancel="_handleValueHelpClose">
    <StandardListItem

        title="{CategoryName}"
         />
</SelectDialog>
```

Edit: As it seems that you are using SAP WebIDE, it would be a good idea to add services.odata.org as a [Destination in HCP](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/07/how-to-use-northwind-odata-service-with-sap-river-rde/)

Comment: Now I get same errors in my console.

The errors are:

Uncaught (in promise) Object {message: "Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Fail…ces.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata'.", request: undefined, response: undefined}

Uncaught (in promise) Object {xmlDoc: document}

sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs.js?eval:17 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 501

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: That's a Cross-origin error that you get, as you are referencing the service from a domain which does not allow cross-origin requests. You should add the Service as a Destination in HCP or run your browser in Cross-origin mode.

Comment: I ran in the Internet Explorer and I don't get any error in console, but the Dialog don't show any data

Comment: you can enable cross-origin in IE: Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options. Select the Security Tab & click on Custom Level button. In the Settings under Miscellaneous > Access data sources across domains, select Enable

Comment: I would suggest you to add a HCP Destination for the service as that is the standard way of implementing a service. You can refer to the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3a16c7a2f1e944deb000db49e5ece6be.html) and [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/07/how-to-use-northwind-odata-service-with-sap-river-rde/) SCN Post

Answer (score 0):

You binded the items aggregation of the SelectDialog to the "/CategoryName" collection, but this collection does not exist in the OData service. I guess you meant to bind it to the Categories collection instead.

Comment: Now I get same errors in my console.

The errors are:

Uncaught (in promise) Object {message: "Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Fail…ces.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata'.", request: undefined, response: undefined}

Uncaught (in promise) Object {xmlDoc: document}

sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs.js?eval:17 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 501

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)